# How to make an aggregate in Reactable without using the NA values

Tags: r, reactable

I am trying to aggregate with the reactable package using `ASP <- reactable::colDef(aggregate = 'mean')` but it returns NAs because one of the rows has an NA.

Is there a way to tell `reactable::colDef()` to ignore the NA values and calculate the mean with the non-NA values?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
ASP = colDef(
footer = function(values) {
mean(na.omit(values))
}
)
```

For reference, I specified "NA" for missing values in my data frame.